# Add UIViewControllers View as a subView of another UIViewController view

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have a UiView called TestView which I have added as a subView of my NumberViewController.

On start of my app, My rootViewController is PaperViewController, this has some UIButtons which I have added through xib, Now I wanted to add NumberViewController's view as a subView of PaperViewController, so I did this

```
 NumberViewController = [[NumberViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NumberViewController" bundle:nil];
    NumberViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:NumberViewController.view];
    NumberViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NumberViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Now this is hidden because, I will unhide it on click of some button and then I will show NumberViewContrller's  view.This all works fine.

But suppose I added some buttons in PaperViewController through code, and then unhide NumberViewController's view , then both views overlap.

I am not understanding what is the problem, and what mistake I am making. So friends please help me out

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: Why do you add the second view controller view as subview instead presenting the second view controller?

Comment: @jcesar bcoz, I want to show it instantly and not as modalView.

Comment: Can you please post your code how you add button programatically and unhide view ?

Comment: Sorry,your question is not clear to me, what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Jennis, the code to add button programatically is the std one.

Comment: @iDeveloper, I want that both views should not over lap, and NumberViewController's view should be above PaperViewController's view

Comment: Ok, did you try to bring the NumberViewController to front? something like `[self.View bringSubviewToFront:numberViewControllerView];`

Comment: But why do you use 2 view controllers? you can use just one, with the current view and the view you have on numberViewController, and then hide/show and bring to top

Comment: @iDeveloper, not working.

Comment: @Ranjit, can you provide some sort of code where you trying to do all these stuff?

Comment: @iDeveloper, everything I have shown, I think you should try this and check

Comment: @iDeveloper, and everyone, it is working now,

Comment: Hmmm,good. write down the issue as well so any other person facing same problem can get help from your experience.

Comment: Ok, I will do it shortly

Answer (score 2):

Add UIView in Header:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *addChildView;
```

In `- (void)viewDidLoad` - Method do this:

```
  ChildViewController *nonSystemsController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];

    nonSystemsController.view.frame = self.addChildView.bounds;    
    [self.addChildView addSubview:nonSystemsController.view];

    [nonSystemsController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:nonSystemsController];
```